# Sugarcrm 6.5.18 - Convert Lead - Add option to schedule a meeting

Tags: sugarcrm

I am looking to add an additional option to schedule meeting. I have added another field (dropdown) in the module meeting which works perfectly in the Meetings page however, I am having great difficulty getting the dropdown to appear in the convert lead section (Schedule Meeting) as an option? Does anyone know how to do this? I am using SugarCE 6.5.18. Thanks for any replies in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hej John,

go to your Studio and add the `Dropdown` to the **QuickCreate** Layout of **Meeting**s Module and it will be visible in your **Leads** Module, if you click on create **Schedule Meeting**.

[image: Quick Create in Studio]

And now also visible in Leads Module:

[image: Dropdown also in Leads]

Comment: Patrick,
I've tried that but it's still not appearing. I checked all the permissons and they all seem to OK as well. What else do you think could be at fault?

Comment: @JohnSmith you also checked the file: custom/modules/Meetings/metadata/quickcreatedefs.php if there was the field also inserted? Something like this in my case of "Tag" Field:
`array (
          0 =>
          array (
            'name' => 'day_c',
            'studio' => 'visible',
            'label' => 'LBL_DAY',
          ),
          1 => '',
        ),`

Comment: Patrick, This is how my code looks. I added some more than what is needed just incase something else is throwing it. 1 => array ( 0 => array ( 'name' => 'day_list_c', 'studio' => 'visible', 'label' => 'LBL_DAY_LIST', ), ), However I noticed when looking at the field names. Its called * day_list_c. Does the star mean something? When I click to edit it It's just called day_list_c.

Comment: The * only means that you've created that field in Sugars' Studio. Well, i would suggest to undo all changes and try it again, if it still wont work, you can report an issue [here](https://github.com/sugarcrm/sugarcrm_dev/issues)